# aggretaing data from json objects and creating hierarchies

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, aggregate

I have to create a tree structured table with some data given in the form of json array.

let us take an example array

```
array :
[
{ "continent": "Asia", "country":"India", "population": 100, "GDP":4},
{ "continent": "Asia", "country":"china", "population": 130, "GDP":20},
{ "continent": "Asia", "country":"Pakistan", "population": 20, "GDP":1},
{ "continent": "Europe", "country":"UK", "population": 2, "GDP":15},
{ "continent": "Europe", "country":"France", "population": 4, "GDP":16},
{ "continent": "Europe", "country":"Germany", "population": 5, "GDP":21}
]
```

the table is like a tree which can be expanded or collapsed.
let the tree be like,

```
    continent          country         population       GDP

    Asia           +                   250               25

    Europe         -                   11                52
                       UK              2                 15
                       France          4                 16
                       Germany         5                 21
```

on the above table we expanded Europe, in the below table we expand Asia.

```
    continent           country            population       GDP

    Asia           -                       250              25
                        India              100              4
                        China              130              20
                        Pakisthan          20               1

    Europe       +                         11               52
```

please help me in creating the table with aggregated values.
Thanks :)

Comment: I dont know how to proceed :(

Comment: Folks at this site don't mind helping someone when they are stuck at a particular point, but most of us won't just give "ready-made" solutions to problems.  In the answers I'll give a rough guide for what needs to be done but it won't be a working solution.

Comment: atleast provide me a way to aggregate, I am not aksing about the whole thing right from UI design! :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function showHide(){
  var td = this,
      tr = this.parentElement,
      next = td.nextElementSibling;
  if(tr.className == 'visible'){
    var rowSpan = td.rowSpan;
    td.oldRowSpan = rowSpan;
    td.rowSpan = next.rowSpan = 1;
    tr.className = 'collapsed';
    for(var i=1; i<rowSpan; ++i){
      tr = tr.nextElementSibling;
      tr.className = 'hidden';
    }
  }else{
    td.rowSpan = next.rowSpan = td.oldRowSpan;
    rowSpan = td.oldRowSpan;
    tr.className = 'visible';
    for(var i=1; i<rowSpan; ++i){
      tr = tr.nextElementSibling;
      tr.className = '';
    }
  }
}
var data = [
  { "continent": "Asia", "country":"India", "population": 100, "GDP":4},
  { "continent": "Asia", "country":"china", "population": 130, "GDP":20},
  { "continent": "Asia", "country":"Pakistan", "population": 20, "GDP":1},
  { "continent": "Europe", "country":"UK", "population": 2, "GDP":15},
  { "continent": "Europe", "country":"France", "population": 4, "GDP":16},
  { "continent": "Europe", "country":"Germany", "population": 5, "GDP":21}
], obj = {};
for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
  var continent = data[i].continent,
      arr = obj[continent] = obj[continent] || [];
  arr.push([data[i].country,data[i].population,data[i].GDP]);   
}
var table = document.createElement('table'),
    thead = document.createElement('thead'),
    tbody = document.createElement('tbody'),
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
var keys = ['','Continent','Country','Population','GDP'];
for(var i=0; i<keys.length; ++i){
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(keys[i]));
  tr.appendChild(td);
}
thead.appendChild(tr);
table.appendChild(thead);
for(var i in obj) {
  var dataArr = [];
  tr = document.createElement('tr'),
    td = document.createElement('td');
  td.rowSpan = obj[i].length + 1;
  td.onclick = showHide;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
  td.rowSpan = obj[i].length + 1;
  tr.appendChild(td);
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
  for(var j=0; j<obj[i].length; ++j){
    var subTr =  document.createElement('tr');
    for(var k=0; k<obj[i][j].length; ++k){
      td = document.createElement('td');
      if(k>0) dataArr[k] = (dataArr[k] || 0) + obj[i][j][k];
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[i][j][k]));
      subTr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(subTr);
  }
  for(var j=0; j<dataArr.length; ++j){
    td = document.createElement('td')
    td.className = 'data-sum';
    if(dataArr[j]) td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dataArr[j]));
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  tr.className = 'visible';
}
table.appendChild(tbody);
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%
}
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.hidden, .visible > .data-sum {
  display: none;
}
.collapsed > :first-child, .visible > :first-child {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.collapsed > :first-child:before {
  content: '[+]';
  font-family: monospace;
}
.visible > :first-child:before {
  content: '[-]';
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: @SoftwareFarmer Then, you want to aggregate values (that you get using AJAX, for example) after drawing the table?

Comment: yes exactly, when we collapse the country column, then aggregated value of all the countries of a continent must be displayed in the population, gdp columns. refer my question once!

Comment: @SoftwareFarmer Ah, then you don't want to add new rows, you only want to sum the values! I should have looked better your example

Comment: the problem is if there are more levels of hierarchies, then simply aggregating is applicable it seems. we need some sort of methods to make it possible for any levels of hierarchies (for example countries, states, cities..)

Answer (score 2):

You mention `javascript` in your tags, so I assume you need the answer in JS.  I'm giving you keywords that you'll need to study up on.

First, declare the variable.

```
var regions = [
  { "continent": "Asia", "country":"India", "population": 100, "GDP":4},
  { "continent": "Asia", "country":"china", "population": 130, "GDP":20},
  { "continent": "Asia", "country":"Pakistan", "population": 20, "GDP":1},
  { "continent": "Europe", "country":"UK", "population": 2, "GDP":15},
  { "continent": "Europe", "country":"France", "population": 4, "GDP":16},
  { "continent": "Europe", "country":"Germany", "population": 5, "GDP":21}
];
```

Then, you need something to hold the various answers:

var results = {};  // Note, this is an object.  Not an array.

Next, loop over the array with standard loop processing.  A `for` loop if you need to support older browsers, `.forEach` if you can only target newer ones.

With each loop, see if `continent` exists in `results`.  If not, add the `property` with a value of 0.

Then just accumulate the `GDP` in `results[<continent>]`